# Asterisk Penalty for dynamic Agents

Tags: asterisk

Is there a way to use penalty with dynamic agents to order agents call distribution for received calls in a queue?

We are using linear ring strategy and this only order calls to dynamic agents by their order in the login.

Answer (score 0):

The penalty is set when the member is added to the queue. If you want to control this you may remove and re-add the member to the queue, but maybe this can cause some misbehaviour.

If you really want to do this, you may consider using realtime agents. Then you will be able to control the penalty without the need for removing member from the queue.

[edited] adding some comments about Asterisk Realtime Architecture

You can check that you're using dynamic agents or realtime by CLI

```
# rasterisk -x 'queue show'
```

It should be something like

```
my_queue has 0 calls (max unlimited) in 'leastrecent' strategy (4s holdtime, 249s talktime), W:0, C:3834, A:130, SL:0.0% within 0s
   Members:
      member.one (sip/4206) (realtime) (In use) has taken 2 calls (last was 2457 secs ago)
      member.two (sip/4234) (realtime) (In use) has taken 5 calls (last was 693 secs ago)
      member.three (sip/4261) (realtime) (In use) has taken 6 calls (last was 638 secs ago)
   No Callers
```

About realtime, taken from voip-info.org: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime

> In the new RealTime architecture, all database specific code is moved
>   to database specific drivers. The channel just calls a generic routine
>   to do database lookup. Much cleaner, simpler and manageable from a
>   coding standpoint.

It means that every state, penalty, member stays in the database and therefore you can change them at your own will. Let me know if i can be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks lucas for your reply, and what do you mean by real-time agents?